# Chromium Google search autocomplete not working on Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, google

I installed Chromium on Mint 20 using apt following the docs [here](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chromium.html)

```
$ apt list chromium
Listing... Done
chromium/ulyana,now 87.0.4280.66~linuxmint1+ulyana amd64 [installed]
```

Then I added Google as the default search engine for Chromium.

[image: config in chromium]

But when I type into Chromium's address bar, no suggestions from Google show up.

[image: only history and previous searches show up]

Google autocomplete is working just fine after adding to Firefox following [these docs](https://www.linuxmint.com/searchengines.php). Also the autocomplete works for other search engines (e.g., DuckDuckGo) included by default with the Chromium install.

Did I install or configure Chromium wrong, or is there something in Mint 20 blocking me from using Google search with Chromium? (I've never had this problem on Ubuntu, macOS, etc.).

#### Edit

Here are my Chromium settings for "Sync and Google services". I have autocomplete enabled. Tried with all enabled, still didn't work.

[image: autocomplete settings in Chromium]

Search engines that came default like DuckDuckGo initially had autocomplete working in Chromium, but when I removed them and re-added them autocomplete stopped working for them also.

Comment: Is it enabled in `chrome://settings/syncSetup`? IIRC, it has to be turned on manually in Chromium.

Comment: @KGIII yes I have "Autocomplete searches and URLs" set to enabled and (the other two disabled.) Autocomplete is working for other search providers e.g. DuckDuckGo. Updating the question to clarify

Comment: Updated question. Is there any additional debugging I could do that might be in the right direction?

Comment: Not that I can think of off-hand. I've seen this before but the resolution isn't in my notes.

Comment: @KGIII thanks it helped, I put in an own answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Chromium on Ubuntu 20.04 address bar autocomplete search

#### TL;DR

#### `chrome://settings/syncSetup` => `Autocomplete searches and URLs` turn on

#### Background

It does not help the OP, but people coming from Google might be helped.
I recently [installed with this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206153/321926) Chrome on `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` because I did not want the `snap` package.
Version of install was:

`89.0.4389.114 (Developer Build) built on Debian 10.9, running on Debian bullseye/sid (64-bit)`.

Autocomplete did not work in the adress bar with `Google Search`.I followed the comment of @KGIII. In the address Bar enter:
`chrome://settings/syncSetup`

Then confirm by turning it on and you got it:

```
Autocomplete searches and URLs
Sends some cookies and searches from the address bar and search box to your default search engine
```